# Как написать функцию, которая отображает время на сайте каждые полчаса?

Tags: php

Начал писать функцию, но столкнулся с проблемой, как выводить время каждые полчаса? Например сейчас 17-50, затем 18-20 и так далее до бесконечности, пока сайт будет работать с помощью PHP?

Comment: если живые часы, то надо писать на js. и такого в сети, думаю, валом

Comment: Нет, мне не нужны живые часы, просто вывод времени каждые 30мин, использую функцию

Comment: Конечно, можно использовать цикл `while` и функцию `sleep`, но что-то мне подсказывает, что Вы не хотите это делать в `php` :) Крайне рекомендую использовать для этого `JavaScript` и функцию `setInterval`.

Comment: «пока сайт будет работать» – пока он открыт у пользователя, или пока сервер не сломается?

Comment: Пока сервер работает, но я очень хочу это сделать без использования Cron...

Answer (score 4):

можно на страницу добавить [*meta-заголовок*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1800">
```

который порекомендует браузеру обновить страницу через `1800` секунд (т.е., полчаса).

Answer (score 4):

Мой хрустальный шар выдал такую версию: требуется выводить время, округлённое до полчасов, начиная с заданного.

```
$start = strtotime('2015-07-01 21:10:00'); // начало отсчёта
$elapsed = floor((time() - $start)/1800)*1800; // округление до получаса
echo date( 'H:i', $start + $elapsed);
```

Answer (score 2):

В PHP нет понятия "каждые тридцать минут", пока вы используете стандартную форму применения PHP с вызывающим веб-сервером. PHP "живет" только от начала запроса и до его конца, с точки зрения вывода это вообще одномоментное действие - т.е. то, что уже выведено, является константой и никак не изменяется. Вам нужно не "выводить каждые полчаса", а "выводить время, ближайшее к следующему времени в расписании, определяемом получасовым интервалом". Таким образом, тербуется что-то вроде такого:

```
$offset = 20 * 60; // сдвиг в 20 минут или 1200 секунд
$period = 30 * 60; // период, определяющиий расписание - полчаса
$periods = (time() - strtotime('today') - $offset) / $period;
$expectedTime = strtotime('today') + $periods * $period + $offset;
echo date('H:i:s', $expectedTime);
```

Возможно, потребуется поиграться с временной зоной.